# Increasing bar width in bar chart using Altair

Tags: python, altair

I have the following dataframe and want to use `altair` library in Python to plot my bar chart. However, I couldn't figure out how to expand the width of each bar (same as `width=0.5` parameter in `matplotlib`).

```
import pandas as pd 
from altair import * 

ls = [[   1,  734], [   2, 1705], [   3, 2309],
      [   4, 2404], [   5, 2022], [   6, 1538],
      [   7, 1095], [   8,  770], [   9,  485],
      [  10,  312], [  11,  237], [  12,  153],
      [  13,  103], [  14,   69], [  15,   47],
      [  16,   39], [  17,   43], [  18,   28],
      [  19,   18]]
df = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=['n_authors', 'n_posters'])
```

Here is plotting function using `altair`

```
bar_chart = Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=X('n_authors', title='Number of Authors in a Poster'), 
    y=Y('n_posters', title='Number of Posters'),
).configure_facet_cell(
    strokeWidth=1.0,
    height=200,
    width=300
 )
bar_chart.display()
```

The plot looks like below from the script:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer of @Nipun doesn't work any more. After some experimenting, I could obtain the desired result with `size` instead of `barSize`. (I only tested it in Jupyter Lab.)

```
from pandas import *
from altair import *

ls = [[   1,  734], [   2, 1705], [   3, 2309],
      [   4, 2404], [   5, 2022], [   6, 1538],
      [   7, 1095], [   8,  770], [   9,  485],]
df = DataFrame(ls, columns=['X', 'Y'])

Chart(df).mark_bar(size=20).encode(x='X', y='Y')
```

Comment: Did you found a way to increase the spacing as well ? When the size is increased like that, it starts to overlap the neighbor bars.

Comment: @Tarantula you should just increase the width of the plot then; e.g. `Chart(df).mark_bar(size=20).encode(x='X', y='Y').properties(width=800)`

Comment: Is there a way to get this to scale with zoom when using interactive?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `barSize` argument. See more here for [Mark Configuration](https://altair-viz.github.io/API.html#altair.MarkConfig).

#### Solution

```
bar_chart = Chart(df).mark_bar(barSize=20).encode(
    x=X('n_authors', title='Number of Authors in a Poster'), 
    y=Y('n_posters', title='Number of Posters'),
).configure_facet_cell(
    strokeWidth=1.0,
    height=200,
    width=300
 )
bar_chart.display()
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Nipun! I was looking at `configure_facet_cell` for a while. I didn't know that you can configure in `mark_bar` right away.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: FYI, the `barSize` property **no longer works**. `size` should be used instead.