# Python Pandas 2 Column Relation

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

1st colunn : Weapon

2nd column : Pepetrator_Age

What i am trying to find is which weapon is popular in which age.
[image]

For example i am trying to draw a similar graph like this:
[image]

For example y axis should be number of cases
x axis age of Perpetrator

and lines are weapon type that Perpetrator used

You can copy paste this to jupyter to initialize dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv("hdb.csv", low_memory=False)
cols = data.columns
cols = cols.map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'))
data.columns = cols
#clear the unnecessary data here
data = data.drop(['Agency_Code', 'Victim_Ethnicity', 'Agency_Name','Agency_Type', 'Perpetrator_Ethnicity', 'Victim_Count', 'Perpetrator_Count'], axis=1)
data = data[data.Perpetrator_Age != "0"]
data = data[data.Perpetrator_Age != ""]
data = data[data.Perpetrator_Age != " "]
data = data[data.Victim_Sex != "Unknown"]
data = data[data.Victim_Race != "Unknown"]
data = data[data.Perpetrator_Sex != "Unknown"]
data = data[data.Perpetrator_Race != "Unknown"]
data = data[data.Relationship != "Unknown"]
data = data[data.Weapon != "Unknown"]
data
```

Data set here:
https://www.kaggle.com/jyzaguirre/us-homicide-reports

Comment: Please post code to generate your data. This will be better than posting an image and it is more likely someone will post a reply. :)

Comment: u can download it here https://ufile.io/br1nhwl4

Comment: I believe that you are looking for a [countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#seaborn.countplot) and not a line plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this grouping of data is likely better shown as a grouped bar chart, such as in Seaborn's [`countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#seaborn.countplot), and not in a line plot because you want to color by a specific column (`Weapon`) but you want to show a different column on the x-axis (`Perpetrator_Age`). AFAIK, a line plot will not capture these aggregations simultaneously.

Here is an explicit pandas `groupby` to show the aggregations that you are referencing

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Perpetrator_Age', 'Weapon']).count()

print(df_grouped)
                               Perpetrator_Race  Relationship
Perpetrator_Age Weapon                                       
15              Blunt Object                  1             1
27              Knife                         1             1
36              Rifle                         1             1
42              Strangulation                 2             2
```

Now, you want to show the first index level (`Perpetrator_Age`) on the x-axis and the second index level `Weapon` must be used to color the plotted data.

Here are a few approaches (that do not require `groupby`)

**Seaborn**

- use [`countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#seaborn.countplot) which will generate a bar plot of counts (corresponding the number of cases or, in general, number of records in each grouping) and it allows you to specify the column to use to group the data
- since you want to color by the `Weapon` column, `countplot` allows the parameter `hue` where you can specify this
- additional links

  - [customize legend title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579663/4057186)
  - [add custom y-axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21487560/4057186)

Imports

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
```

Code

```
ax = sns.countplot(x="Perpetrator_Age", hue="Weapon", data=df)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels)
ax.set_ylabel("Number of cases")
```

[image: Seaborn_approach]

**Altair**

- based on the [multi-series line chart](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multi_series_line.html#multi-series-line-chart) and [grouped bar chart](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart.html#grouped-bar-chart) documentation examples

  - additional links

    - [change bar width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50437343/4057186)

Imports

```
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')
```

Code

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(size=15).encode(
    alt.Y('count(Weapon):Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Number of cases')),
    alt.X('Perpetrator_Age:O', axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=0)),
    color='Weapon:N'
).properties(
    width=250,
    height=250
)
```

[image: Altair approach]

Comment: Hello ! thanks for your awesome answer.I have another question.How do i show  the relationship between perpetrator age and total number of incident in a correct way ? I mean if i draw a graph its clear that its declining when they get older, but what is the correct way to do this in data science  thanks

Comment: @lastpeony4, if you want to show how total incidents change with `Perpetrator_Age` (without separating them by `Weapon`), then you can `groupby` over `Perpetrator_Age`, count the cases and then just use a simple line chart to show the result: `ax = df.groupby(['Perpetrator_Age'])['Weapon'].count().plot(kind='line'); ax.set_ylabel("Number of cases");`